# In the UK, can documents obtained through Freedom of Information be shared with friends?

Tags: confidentiality, freedom-of-information

If you have obtained certain documents from a government agency in the UK through a Freedom of Information request, are you allowed to send a copy of these documents to a friend who might also be interested in looking at these documents? Parts of the obtained documents have already been redacted by the government agency as they deemed necessary (to protect certain details, presumably).

Answer (score 3):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In the United States, information released through the federal Freedom of Information (FoI) process, or any of the various state-level versions of FoI, is considered public information. The person who receives it may share it at will, or publish it. Indeed many such inquiries are made by news reporters who intend to publish the information, and many others are routinely posted to various web sites.

I suspect that the law on this point in the UK is similar, but I have not checked it.